# ffmpeg- add 2 watermarks in one video

Tags: ffmpeg

I need to add 2 watermarks to my videos one in left one in right. How can I do that?

```
ffmpeg -re -i file1.mp4 -i "/var/www/logo/logo.png" -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=640:360[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=15:15' -i "/var/www/html/am.png" -filter_complex '[0:v]scale=640:360[bg];[bg][1:v]overlay=W-w-15:15' -vcodec
```

causes the error

```
at most one video stream is supported in flv
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 2):

Use just one filtergraph (just one instance of `-filter_complex`):

```
ffmpeg -i file1.mp4 -i "/var/www/logo/logo.png" -i "/var/www/html/am.png" -filter_complex \
"[0:v]scale=640:360[bg0]; \
 [bg0][1:v]overlay=15:15[bg1]; \
 [bg1][2:v]overlay=W-w-15:15" \
-c:v libx264 output.flv
```

Comment: Of course if you don't want scaling it's scale=0:0

Comment: @VijayKumarKanta Or omit the scale filter.

Comment: I had trouble removing it. It won't work without it. An example without scaling?

Comment: @VijayKumarKanta `ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -i image1.png -i image2.jpg -filter_complex "[0][1]overlay[bg];[bg][2]overlay=W-w" output`

Comment: Great, will use that and get back.